# Android: HttpUrlConnection variable post issue

Tags: php, android, httpurlconnection

Am sending variables using `HttpURLConnection` from `android` to `.php` file in server. I have strange issue and i don't know how to solve it.

This way works:

```
for(int i=1; i<parameters.length; i++) {
    postDataParams.put("userInfo" , parameters[i]);    
}

$userInfo=$_POST['userInfo'];
```

But I need to post as many variables as I have and its not working:

```
for(int i=1; i<parameters.length; i++) {
    postDataParams.put("userInfo"+i , parameters[i]);
}

$userInfo=$_POST['userInfo1'];
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what is wrong with second one? What is the output you are seeing?

Comment: how about send a json string ?

Comment: king, could you give me example and how to retrieve json string in php file?